# Automate Global Protect VPN connection in Python

Tags: python, automation, vpn

I was asked to use Python to automate processes that download files from multiple servers. In order to connect to the servers, I must connect to the Global Protect VPN first. That said, in order to automate the process, I must also automate the VPN connection/disconnection. I tried to search for information about how to automate the GP VPN connection in Python but couldn't find any helpful posts. Could anyone please help with it? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a command line client available? If yes, it shouldn't be too hard to use python to connect. If there is only a proprietary windows client without cmd interface then it will be hard to almost impossible. That is the problem with proprietary software... you could use openvpn and search for a vpn provider that supports standard software.

Comment: @Frieder Could you please elaborate more about the command line client? So I am using Python in PyCharm to write the connection code. I assume PyCharm is a command line client? Sorry if the question is dumb:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use global protect from CLI so I guess it`s easy to call the CLI commands that you need from python.

On my ubuntu system, if I want to launch the GUI I can type in my terminal:

```
globalprotect launch-ui
```

If I want to connect to a VPN server from CLI (without launching the UI) I can use:

```
globalprotect connect --portal <gp-portal>
```

You can find more information here: [Palo Alto GlobalProtect](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-linux/use-the-globalprotect-app-for-linux.html).

To use the above CLI from python: [Call shell/CLI from python.](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/)

Also, keep in mind:

> When you use certificate-based authentication, the first time you connect without a root CA certificate, the GlobalProtect app and GlobalProtect portal exchange certificates. The GlobalProtect app displays a certificate error, which you must acknowledge before you authenticate. When you next connect, you will not be prompted with the certificate error message.

If that is the case for you, you can specify the location of the certificate:

```
globalprotect import-certificate --location /home/mydir/Downloads/cert_client_cert.p12
```

Refer to [1](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-linux/use-the-globalprotect-app-for-linux.html) for more CLI commands.

Comment: I am unable to use the same in Windows system.
Can you please help me out?

Comment: I think this applies only to linux.